# Downloading directly to external hdd, strange behaviour on local disk

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, browser, cache, temporary-files

I am trying to download directly to an external hdd, and I have noticed strange behaviour.

I'm on windows 8.1. Let's say I have 500mb of free space left on my local disk and wish to download a 1gb file from a web browser. So I click 'Save As' and choose the external hdd. Now as I check file explorer, I do see a partial file appearing on the external hdd, but the free space on my local disk is rapidly dropping. At the same rate as the download speed... Eventually the free local space becomes zero and the download just pauses at halfway. When I try again and clear 1gb of free local space, the download completes then the free space is restored to 1gb again, instantly, and the downloaded file is on the external.

**So it seems like it's just downloading to the local disk first, then moving the file to the external** (at an insane speed). This a problem, because if I want to download a bigger file, it'll be very hard to clear up space as my local disk is only 22gb, and space is always tight there. So essentially, the 'save as' feature is useless?
I've tried with IE, firefox and chrome, and the same weird behaviour occurs. Though it doesn't happen when I download with utorrent for some reason.

I've also tried looking in the 'Temporary Internet Files' directory to see if any large files were being written, and they weren't. I've also tried changing that directory to somewhere on the external hdd, but the strange behaviour still occurs.

What's going on? Is this normal?

Any feedback will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 (or any operating system) requires some available disk space in order to function. 500MB is definitely in the danger zone. I'd be uncomfortable with less than 10GB, or at a minimum, double the amount of RAM you have. When Windows runs out of disk space, it becomes unstable, may freeze, crash, and may even corrupt your files and/or files necessary to run Windows.  Today, 22GB is a tiny hard drive, and was barely enough space to install Windows 8.1 when it was initially released. Since then, additional space used by Windows Updates might grow to more than 22GB. This is w/o any space allocated for your programs or data. Best course of action is to shut it down before it corrupts itself.  Next you have a couple choices: (a) new computer, then remove your 22gb drive and connect it to new computer (either internally, or using an appropriate external hdd enclosure) for transfer of your data.  (b) new larger harddrive, then use harddrive-transfer tools to migrate and expand your current drive to larger drive. Some new harddrives come with software to do this. (a) gives you the benefit of new hardware, latest version Windows, but requires you reinstall any programs that you installed since you got the Windows 8.1 system. (b) could be accomplished for less money, but may be more work and leaves you running old Windows and system hardware.

Comment: I'm not interested in buying  or using a new computer anytime soon. It is a HP Stream (which I love) and internal emmc drive which cannot be replaced (I think). I've disabled windows updates so that's not an issue (I've weighed the pros and cons before making this decision). Thanks for your time, but I don't feel like my question was answered. Unless you're saying, yes it is normal

Comment: Having only 500mb of free space has never caused me any problems, except when I need to download large files like now, and every once in a while, via a web browser. Other programs seem to be able to do 'save as' properly so I can usually download to an external directly

Comment: you're right, I didn't answer.  I'm pretty certain your browser is downloading initially to a temporary folder, where once the download is complete, but before placing it in your intended folder, it will have a chance to pass the file off to Windows Defender or other 3rd party anti-virus for scanning. Once the file is deemed safe, it then transfers it to the intended folder. I don't think it's practical to attempt to change this behavior. But then I also feel you are asking for much more trouble by connecting to the Internet with updates disabled.

Comment: You might try wget for windows https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ .  wget is a command line download utility, which, unless Windows intervenes, should download directly to intended folder.